# Visual Studio ASP.Net Impersonate Identity Issue

Tags: asp.net, authentication, visual-studio-2013, impersonation

I am currently using windows authentication for my intranet asp.net site.  I would like to have a portion of my site only be available to those in a windows user group(admins) that I specify, and give access to.  Thus far, I have this working fine, with the ASP.net impersonation in IIS set to "Authenticated User."  I would also like to download a file from a network location to the clients machine.  I am doing this via the following code:

```
Protected Sub Button1Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim path3 As String = "file path here"
    Dim fi As New FileInfo(path3)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application\msword"
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & fi.Name)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(fi.FullName)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush()
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Close()
End Sub
```

This works as well, but only if I switch the ASP.net impersonation from Authenticated User to a specific user.  I have checked, and both the specific user and the authenticated user have access to the file path.  For example, I am signed in under the windows account JonW, which is part of the group DOMAIN USERS.  I know for a fact that DOMAIN USERS has access to the file I want to download.

If I don't use a specific user, then when I click the button to try to download the file, a windows security pops up and asks for my information.  When I put in the info (which I don't want to have to do anyway as I'm already signed in), it waits for 15 seconds then asks again.  This repeats itself 5 or so times until it tells me that I don't have access (which I know I do).

Thus, the obvious solution is to use a specific impersonated account, correct?  Nope, because when I try to gain access to my admins section of the site, I cannot because it is using the specific impersonated user, as opposed to the authenticated user that is part of the admin group.  I could give the specific impersonated account access to that section of the site, but then everyone would be able to get in, which I don't want.

So my question is either how can I use a specific impersonated user to download the file, and the authenticated user to gain access to the admin section, or, how can I just use the authenticated user the whole time and get rid of that windows security pop up, and have it use the authenticated users credentials automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused as to why you think you need to impersonate anyone in the first place.  There is no need to impersonate anyone unless you need network credentials specific to that user, which most often is not the case.

For example, in your case you can simply run the site as the App Pool User, which, behind the scenes will authenticate over the network as the credentials of the machine on the domain.  So, if your IIS servers name is "Webserver" then you need only give `\\Domain\$Webserver` access to the share/folder/resources necessary to access the files, then you control access to those resources in your application by using standard Windows Authentication.

So, if you don't want "normal" users to access this portion of the site, you just deny them access via the standard ASP.NET authentication tools (web.config, etc..).

If you need to give users access to the area, but only allow them to access some files, but not others, then it becomes more complicated, but still not overly difficult.